# Why are there only few choices for flagging inappriopriate site of the network?

Tags: discussion, flagging, migration, stackexchange

[image: Sites]

Only these 5 are available. I feel like some common options are missing, such as https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com, which gets confused a lot because there are a lot of older recommendation questions with many upvotes that are still on SuperUser. They're also usually way more popular in search engines than Software Recommendations ones.

I know that a separate "it's asking for product recommendation (...)" reason can be used, but then these questions often end up closed instead of being moved there, which doesn't help solving the issue of software recommendations being more popular here than there either...

Comment: Limitation of the platform, and in all honesty, most content that is migrated is ultimately rejected by the target community. Ultimately, it’s better for the author of the out of scope content, to have it deleted so they can have it submitted. Most users fail to identify content that should be improved before it’s migrated, and most users, ultimately don’t improve their contributions so I can be migrated. The fact users, **fail** to determine what’s within scope, is ultimately on them. I feel I am under not demand, to improve content, that should never have been submitted in the first place

Comment: Only 5 are allowed under the current site configuration - I think that limit applies to all SE sites.

Comment: Before I saw this, I'd already raised a new question on what might be done with the software recs close explanation. https://meta.superuser.com/questions/15008/software-recs-better-user-guidance Personally, I'm with the majority here that simply migrating doesn't help 'fix' a question to that target stack. Better for the user to ask in a way that fits that site properly. The link is just asking for a better way to inform them of that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Jeff Atwood, in 2011](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/96345/1359324), said

> **This is a "Don't Make Me Think" barrier; we don't want to present closers with a list of 12 different destinations and make them suss out which one is correct. There should be 4 most frequently correct destinations + meta**.

You might want to learn more from a more recent post. In such case, please checkout: [A proposed philosophy of question migration](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/285467/1359324).

Related FAQ: [What is migration and how does it work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/10249/1359324)

##### Migrating questions to Software Recommendation.

A question not originally intended to be posted on that site is unlikely to be a good fit for it. Please check out their [tour](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/tour) and [how-to-ask](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask). If you find a recent exemplary question in Super User that is a good fit for that site, I suggest you discuss the migration of such question [As a moderator](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/114/ask-a-super-user-moderator) chatroom. You might have to be prepared to sustain your arguments.

##### Related

- [More options when flagging for migration](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/96205/1359324) [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request) [status-declined](/questions/tagged/status-declined) (from 2011)
- [Should some communities have more than 4 migration targets?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/118685/1359324) (from 2012)

Comment: Thanks for finding these, I'll mark it as best answer, even though IMO bunch of these reasonings are straight up nonsense. E.g. newly asked questions are much more likely to not be a fit than migrated ones, as migration happens is done by experienced users.

Comment: @Destroy666 Thank you for your message. By the way, I have noticed that some arguments today may seem unreasonable, although they may have been reasonable when they were made. I am currently working on mapping the rules of the [so] conceptual model, as well as the implementation and related community norms (such as rules, policies, etc.) so that I can better understand the current situation and support feature requests. If you are interested, here is a related post: [What tag is used for SE rules and their respective enforcement instruments?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/388949/1359324)